# DataFrame merge on column gives NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames with the first df:

```
indegree interrupts Subject
1          2        Weather
2          3        Weather
4          5        Weather
```

The second join:

```
Subject interrupts_mean indegree_mean
weather       2             3
```

But the second is a lot shorter since I made that the means of all the different subjects in the first dataframe.

When I want to merge both DataFrames

```
pd.merge(df,join,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left')
```

it merges but it gives NaNs on the second dataframe in the new dataframe and I suppose it it so since the DataFrames are not the same length. How can I still merge on subject so that the values from the second DataFrame are duplicated in the new DataFrame?

Comment: The issue is that the Subject in df is title case whereas in join data frame it is lower case. Change the join df subject column to title. join.Subject.str.title() and it should work

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it was all that case sensitive.

Comment: No problems, just remember that in python, 'Python' == 'python' equates to False:)